# A simple way to set up automated BDD test environment for Node.js server + SPA javascript framework?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, backbone.js, bdd, single-page-application

Here's my project's setup:

1. Frontend: Angular.js/Backbone.js SPA app
2. Backend: Node.js + NoSQL db as backend
3. Testing:

   - Already have Karma set up for SPA testing (with mock JSON responses)
   - Already have Mocha set up for Node.js, with an isolated "test" environment for test DB setup and teardown

Now the problem comes when I try to set up integrated BDD test (namely, start node servers, start a browser and run SPA tests inside the browser with actual JSON calls to the backend). After some searching, I failed to find a simple and straightforward solution to my problem, so I thought I'd ask here so other people in similar situation may also benefit from the answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest Gruntjs all the way. While on the surface it seems like just another redo of `make(1)`, the community support and HUGE collection of plugins makes it super useful. It will solve all the problems you mentioned plus some.

[Website](http://gruntjs.com)

[Github](http://github.com/gruntjs/grunt)